# pugjs template submit button not working

Tags: javascript, pug

I'm using pugjs for html templating. But a template with submit button not working at all.
template code:

```
extends layout
block content
    div.col-md-12.col-xs-12
        h1 #{html.title}
        - var content = html.contents
        div
            != content
        if(comments.length>0)
            each comment in comments
                div.col-md-12.col-xs-12.comment
                    div
                          !=comment.content
        div.col-md-12.col-xs-12.add
            form(action="/comment/"+message.postId method="post")
                div.input-group
                    input.form-control(type="text" placeholder="Comment:" name="comment" required)
                    span.input-group-btn
                        btn.btn.btn-secondary(type="submit") Submit
```

Other pages using the same layout works, but this template's submit button does not work at all. No network activity was recorded when I clicked the button.
When using the inspection tools to inspect the page,it shows that the form action was correctly binded like
    `<form action="/comment/-1669628617" method="post">`

Comment: tested interface /comment/:id with postman,  work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you should use `input` or `button` tags for that.

```html
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<button type="submit" form="form-name" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I mistaken btn for button